# Formato extenso de fecha y hora en VBA - Excel

Tags: date, vba, visual, basic, date-format

Tengo una fuente de datos con una columna "timestamp" que refleja la hora de la siguiente manera:

2022-08-17T19:20:41.218+0200

Mi duda es si hay alguna manera directa, que no necesite un bucle que recorra todas las files (son decenas de miles al día), para transformar ese formato de fecha en otro más amigable del estilo:

2022-08-17 19:20

He probado lo siguiente, entre otras cosas, sin resultados positivos:

`Rango.Columns("F").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm"`

`Rango.Columns("F").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn"`

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente lo he resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
For Each c In Rango.Cells

        If c.Column = 6 Then
            fecha_formatoSimple= Mid(c.Value, 1, 10) + " " + Mid(c.Value, 12, 5)
            c.Value = fecha_formatoSimple
        End If

Next
```

Pensaba que haciendo un bucle iba a tarda mucho tiempo dada la extensión del archivo, pero resulta que no, han sido pocos segundos.

Utilizo la función Mid para recoger las porciones del String que me interesan (fecha, hora y minuto), lo guardo en un String y reescribo cada celda con ese nuevo formato.